# GL_DEPTH_CLAMP has no effect (reverse z)

Tags: opengl

In an effort to improve cascaded shadow maps, I have looked into using GL_DEPTH_CLAMP and moving the near and far plane just around the actual view frustum instead of the global bounding box. But the use of GL_DEPTH_CLAMP appears to have no effect and the near plane clips the geometry.

I use reverse z as per [Reversed-Z in OpenGL](https://nlguillemot.wordpress.com/2016/12/07/reversed-z-in-opengl/):

The tl/dr version is:

1. Change clip control to 0/1

   ```
   glClipControl(GL_LOWER_LEFT, GL_ZERO_TO_ONE);
   ```
2. Use a floating point depth buffer.
3. Clear the depth buffer to 0

   ```
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

   glClearDepth(0.0f);
   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   ```
4. Change depth test to grater

   ```
   glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
   ```
5. Change the projection matrix to match

The reverse z works really fine, but apparently it messes with GL_DEPTH_CLAMP. If I switch off reverse z GL_DEPTH_CLAMP appears to work as designed; but many other bits in the code get messed up. (It's just not switchable anymore.)

If you look at the documentation of [GL_DEPTH_CLAMP](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glEnable) it states the following:

> If enabled, the -wc ≤ zc ≤ wc plane equation is ignored by view volume clipping (effectively, there is no near or far plane clipping).

My guess is that GL_DEPTH_CLAMP's implementation is just not compatible with reverse z. But I feel like I am missing something. Any idea on how to get GL_DEPTH_CLAMP to working with reverse z?

See the following image of the depth buffers:

[image]

As you can see in the the first cascade, the near plane clips the geometry, it should be all white.

Comment: "*the near plane clips all geometry*" How do you know that?

Comment: Not *all* geometry, that was a typo. Added a picture of the behavior.

Comment: All or most is not the question; the question is how do you *know* that the near plane is clipping something? You say that it should be all white, but why should it be? Where exactly is the geometry that you say shouldn't be clipped? Is it perhaps behind the camera?

Comment: It's a cascaded sun shadow map, it's an orthographic projection, by definition with GL_DEPTH_CLAMP there is no, "behind" the camera. In the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Depth_clamping), there is what you reference: "Note: With perspective projections, you still get clipping with the sides of the viewing volume" But that does not apply, because it's a orthographic projection; like any other cascaded shadow map implementation.